# Defining GattCharacteristic as a Server

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I want to fill my variable "selectedCharacteristic" with

```
    GattCharacteristic selectedCharacteristic
    selectedCharacteristic = Constants.ResultCharacteristicUuid;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It won't convert.

The ResultCharacteristicUuid is from the Microsoft UWP BLE Example.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Constants.cs

My program, which has not much to do with the microsoft example (besides the constants.cs),
opens up a BLE Service on start, along with the Result-Characteristic. It acts as an BLE server, nothing more.

So when my BLE Server started, there should be a simple solution to get the device infos and everything GattCharacteristic needs, or not?

The goal is to write to the characteristic as the server, not as a client.

What do I need to get the ResultCharacteristic-Uuid into selectedCharacteristic ?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you are developing a UWP app that uses Bluetooth API?

Comment: Originally it was a uwp app. the code works also as a wpf app. i made a new thread about this problem. maybe you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833815/write-to-bluetooth-le-characteristic-as-a-server-in-wpf-or-uwp

Answer (score 0):

The UUID should be defined by yourself when you are creating your own service, characteristic. Based on the document- [Bluetooth GATT server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server#attributes-and-uuids), you could generate your custom UUID from Visual Studio through **Tools -> CreateGuid** (use option 5 to get it in the "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-...xxxx" format). This uuid can now be used to declare new local services, characteristics or descriptors.

Comment: Yes, I know. I did that. The solution for my problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71833815/write-to-bluetooth-le-characteristic-as-a-server-in-wpf-or-uwp