# Write to Bluetooth LE Characteristic as a Server in WPF or UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I want to write into a Bluetooth LE Characteristic. (wpf c#, but has to work with UWP also)

I'm not exactly sure how this works, because I want to write a value not as a client, but as the server.
Like in the MS Example:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario3_ServerForeground.xaml.cs

The BLE service and characteristic are created on program start. (not in the MS example, but in my program)

After creating a Characteristic

```
GattLocalCharacteristicResult result = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Constants.ModeCharacteristicUuid, Constants.modeParameters);
       
modeCharacteristic = result.Characteristic;
       
modeCharacteristic.WriteRequested += ModeCharacteristic_WriteRequestedAsync;
```

I want to use this method to write into the characteristic:

```
private async void ModeCharacteristic_WriteRequestedAsync(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattWriteRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        using (args.GetDeferral())
        {
            
            GattWriteRequest request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
            if (request == null)
            {
                // No access allowed to the device.  Application should indicate this to the user.
                return;
            }
           
            request.Respond();

        }
    }
```

Only question to me now is how to write in the Mode-Characteristic.

For example, I simply want to write a 5 into this Characteristic.
What code do I need?

```
ModeCharacteristic_WriteRequestedAsync(modeCharacteristic, 5);
```

doesn't work.

I don't know how to use GattWriteRequestedEventArgs args or the event handler.

Comment: WriteRequested called when a client writes to the characteristic. Server should process received data. You should use ReadRequested event to response to the read requests from a client. Or use NotifyValueAsync to send value changes notifications.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as my ble server starts, the characteristic has to have a specific value written Into it. This value cant be static because it has to change over time. This changing value doesnt come from the client but from the server app. How should I proceed?

Comment: NotifyValueAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I'm now using. It works exactly like it should. First create a characteristic, then adding a subscribedClientsChanged eventhandler.

```
GattLocalCharacteristicResult result = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Constants.ModusCharacteristicUuid, Constants.gattOperandParameters);
        if (result.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
        {
            modeCharacteristic = result.Characteristic;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
modeCharacteristic.SubscribedClientsChanged += ResultCharacteristic_SubscribedClientsChanged;

private void ResultCharacteristic_SubscribedClientsChanged(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, object args)
    {
        ModeNotify(5);
    }

private async void ModeNotify(int computedValue)
    {
        var writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
        writer.WriteInt32(computedValue);

        IReadOnlyList<GattClientNotificationResult> results = await modeCharacteristic.NotifyValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Write to Bluetooth LE Characteristic as a Server in WPF or UWP

You should process write operation in `GattLocalCharacteristic` [ReadRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattlocalcharacteristic.readrequested?view=winrt-22000), when the client send read request, you can get `GattReadRequest` in above event, and then call  `RespondWithValue` to response data that written with data writer.

```
private async void ResultCharacteristic_ReadRequestedAsync(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattReadRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    // BT_Code: Process a read request. 
    using (args.GetDeferral())
    {
        // Get the request information.  This requires device access before an app can access the device's request. 
        GattReadRequest request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
        if (request == null)
        {
            // No access allowed to the device.  Application should indicate this to the user.
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Access to device not allowed", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        var writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
        writer.WriteInt32(resultVal);

        // Can get details about the request such as the size and offset, as well as monitor the state to see if it has been completed/cancelled externally.
        // request.Offset
        // request.Length
        // request.State
        // request.StateChanged += <Handler>

        // Gatt code to handle the response
        request.RespondWithValue(writer.DetachBuffer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks CoCaIceDew, but I got it now with a little different approach.
I didn't know that NotifyValueAsync really writes into the characteristic, but it does.
I wrote an SubscribedClientsChanged eventhandler for the characteristic and put the notify call inside the method.
So every time a client subscribes, it directly gets the right data. That's exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: Cool, please go ahead post your answer below and mark yourself.